# Any help would mean the world! My kitten in severely underweight with a massive stomach

Tags: cats, health, medicines, veterinarian, weight

My kitten is 12 weeks old and is still only 700 grams in weight and tiny in size. She eats and drinks well, is as active as she can be with her belly, but I can feel her spine, all her bones yet her stomach is huge! We went to the vet, first she was shocked that she wasn’t younger and thought we were lying about her age. She said she may have worms, then made us deworm with Panacur (fenbendazole), her poop went from a soft yellowish to now she’s pooping normal brown. Yet still haven’t seen any change in appearance of her stomach and I worry that it’s not going down and causing her all sorts of issues from inability to clean, play and she’s not growing...

Any advice or direction for anyone who has seen something like this before would mean so much to me.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you feeding her special kitten food? It usually has more calories and other nutrients than "normal" cat food. And if nothing changes the vet needs to properly examine her, maybe analyze her blood or scan her stomach. Worms was a good guess, but in her state it might be time for real test instead of more guesses.

Comment: She needs a full vet evaluation; if your current vet can't provide that, you need to see a different vet.

Comment: as the other people say you need to get a second opinion from an other vet,ask the vet to do an ultrasound of your kitten this is to see what the intestines looks like and to see what might be the cause for the big belly.

Answer (score 3):

If she doesn't take any weight and have a massive belly, this is likely to be a worm infestation, as your vet said.

How long has it been from the first worm treatment? The treatment is usually effective within 3 to 5 days. If her state hasn't changed at all, I'll recommend to see another vet. The fact that your vet said 'she MAY have' without doing further research is a huge red flag for me, considering her weight.

She weights at least 300g less than she's supposed to.

Also, when you are checking her poop or her belly, do not touch your face before washing your hands as worms can be transmitted to humans.